# While performing SQL query in python using pandas i am facing the error : TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'schema'

Tags: python, pandas, databricks, azure-databricks, sqldf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YB8gY.png)

Trying to compile sql query in python. Which i used to do very frequently in python. But never faced this error in my past. Help me in fixing the same.

Query:

```py
from pandasql import sqldf
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets

Q10="select bucket,count(*) as COUNT,min(probability) as MINSCORE,max(probability) as MAXSCORE,(avg(probability)*100) as PREDDEFRATE,sum(response) as RESPONSE,count(*)-sum(response) as NONRESPONSE from score group by 1;"

Bucket_Details = sqldf(Q10,globals())
display(Bucket_Details)
```

TypeError: **init**() got multiple values for argument 'schema'

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Why do you keep removing the formatting of the code snippet? Fix the formatting of your question!

Comment: I am also getting this error. Some package that pandasql relies on must have been updated.

Answer (score 7):

Install an earlier version of sqlalchemy. Sqlalchemy version 2.0.0 was released yesterday and isn't compatible with pandasql.

- https://github.com/yhat/pandasql/issues/99

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error. By modifying the code little bit in **google colab**, I was able to perform the query.

```
!pip install pandasql
```

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql
import os
from pandasql import sqldf

data = pd.read_csv('/content/demoCovid_sql.csv')

task1 = "select count(*) from data where Shortness_of_breath = 'True'; "

sqldf(task1, globals())
```

I hope it works with others as well.